# C#: Return IEnumerable when field is not null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

```
public IEnumerable GetAddress()
{
     DataSet ds = DataOps.GetDataSet(string.Format(" select * from Students"));
     DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
     // What goes here?
}
```

I need to use IEnumerable methods

How can i return enumeration of DataRows containing all students that have addresses only?

Comment: What do you mean by "who has address only" I am confused about this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking is

```
DataRow[] dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("Address NOT NULL"); // you want filtering on address column
    foreach (DataRow row in dr)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your student class looks like but here is a mockup

```
    private IEnumerable<Student> GetAddress()
        {
            DataSet ds = DataOps.GetDataSet(string.Format(" select * from Students Where NOT NULL [address]"));
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                yield return new Student   
                                      {                                        
                                          StudentName = row["StudentName "].ToString(),
                                          Address= row["Address"].ToString()
                                      };
            }

        }
```

This should give you some idea of where to go from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot of quick response. Actually the method above has to return the enumeration of DataRows containing all srudents who has address only.       datatable dt has a recordset with all student information. Now I have to filter the records and get the one with address only and return them. i am still confused.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I am filtering the resultset.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to reflect querying students who have an address. Any filtering needs to be handled in the query unless it is something that will be changed client side.

Comment: you could also take the IEnumerable and filter it like this GetAddress().Where(student => ! string.isNullOrEmpty(student.Address))

Answer (score 0):

An `IEnumerable` is just some abstract list which you can iterate through - there are many ways of returning an instance of `IEnumerable`, for example:

- Using the `yield return` construct (.Net 4.0 only)
- Returning a `List<T>`, or array or any other class that already implements `IEnumerable`,

For example:

```
public IEnumerable GetAddress()
{
    DataSet ds = DataOps.GetDataSet(string.Format(" select * from Students"));
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    // The chances are that instead of string you will need a struct or a class
    List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt)
    {
        // This will obviously depend on the table and return type
        retVal.Add((string)row["mycol"]);
    }
}
```

Also, depending on the type returned you probably want to return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead, as it is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks Kragen, i am geting this now:  foreach statement cannot operate on valiable of type system.data.datatable doesnot contain defination for Getenumerator   and as you said code is not happy with string, how do i solve this problem

Comment: @Tenzin What version of the .Net framework are you using and do you have a `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your file?  Sorry I'm not farmiliar with using `DataTables` - I'll try and fix my sample when I get a chance.

Comment: its 3.5 and i just added namespace thats fixed.

Comment: got new issue in line      retVal.Add(row["mycol"]);   unhappy message: 
    system.collection.generic.list<string>.add<string> has some invalid argument

Comment: @Tenzin The problem is that the indexer for row returns an `object`, however the `Add` method is expecting a `string` (as thats the generic type parameter supplied for our list).  I've added a cast which should hopefully fix this.