# how can i solve this problem. The dt have fiften records out of which 10 have null value

Tags: asp.net

how can i get  list of students with values in it. I can not write in select query to retrieve, actually for dataset i will be calling method which returns all students

```
   public IEnumerable GetCallingCodes()
    {
        DataSet ds = DataOps.GetDataSet(string.Format(" select * from students"));
       // foreach 


        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        List<string> retVal = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
           if (row["address"]!=null)
       // line above is not ab
            { retVal.Add((string)row["student"]); }
        }
        return retVal;
```

Comment: yes but i am not good at it. tried but my code did not work. can you help me out.

Comment: Is that solution not help you ? I think you are looking the same . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877600/ienumerable-question-please-help/5877650#5877650

Comment: hey Muhammad, yes thats the same problem. now i can return collection type. but i am still not able to filter the record. I tried to add those records for students whose address is not null. i tried so many different ways. can you please check where am i missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DBNUll.Value` instead of `Null`

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
           if (row["address"]!=DBNull.Value)
       // line above is not ab
            { retVal.Add((string)row["student"]); }
        }
```